# Making an object change direction when reaching a destination

Tags: java, processing

I am very new to coding and my aim is to make and object (a lorry) change destination when it reaches the first one (site). 
As for now, the lorry leaves its original place (concrete plant) and moves to the first site created. The user can add sites with mousePress (I used an array of sites). But then my lorry gets stuck on the first site and doesn't go to the next one. I also want the lorry to go to 2 sites and then come back to the concrete plant to then again leave for 2 sites etc...
Can somebody help me, I am desperate and my deadline is next Monday.

This is my code:

```
Lorry lorry;

int xCoord;
int yCoord;
ArrayList<Site> sites;
int siteSize = 30;

void setup() // What is called once at the beginning
{
  size (500, 500);

  xCoord = int(width/2);
  yCoord = int(height/2);

  //Creating empty Array List where store sites objects
  sites = new ArrayList<Site>();

  //Adding first site
  sites.add(new Site(random(width), random(height), siteSize));

  //storing lorries
  lorry = new Lorry(xCoord, yCoord);
}

void draw() // Draw the background and concrete plant
{
  background (235, 247, 255);
  ellipse(xCoord, yCoord, 60, 60);

  //Calling the sites
  for (int i = sites.size () - 1; i>=0; i--) {
    Site site = sites.get(i);
    site.displaySites();
  }

  //calling the lorry functions
  lorry.updateLorry();
}

void mousePressed() {
  sites.add(new Site(mouseX, mouseY, siteSize));
}

class Site

{
  float x,y;
  float size;

  Site (float xin, float yin, float sin)
  {
    x = xin;
    y = yin;
    size = sin;
  }

  void displaySites()
  {
    rectangle(x, y, 60, 60);
  }
}

class Lorry
{
  PVector location;
  PVector concretePlant;
  PVector velocity;
  boolean changeDirection;
  int siteNumber = 0;
  Site destination;

  Lorry(float xCoord, float yCoord)
  {
    concretePlant = new PVector(xCoord, yCoord); //Initial start point
    location = new PVector(xCoord, yCoord); //Initial start point
    velocity = new PVector(2, 2);
    destination = sites.get(siteNumber);
    changeDirection = false;
  }

  void displayLorry()
  {
    rectangle(location.x, location.y, 30, 30);
  }

  void Move()
  {
    float xdir = destination.x - location.x;
    float ydir = destination.y - location.y;
    PVector dir = new PVector (xdir, ydir);
    dir.normalize();
    location.add(dir);
  }

  void reachDestination()
  {
      if ((destination.x == location.x) && (destination.y == location.y)) {
        siteNumber++; // siteNumber = siteNumber + 1;
        destination = sites.get(siteNumber);
        changeDirection = true;
    }
  }

  void updateLorry()
  {
    displayLorry();
    Move();
    reachDestination();
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll have better luck if you post a [mcve]. We can't run your code because we don't have access to the images and font files you're using. Those aren't actually related to your problem, so it's better if you start with a simpler example that doesn't include them. Maybe start with a circle that travels between some other circles?

Comment: Hey @Lilly, looks like maybe you were looking for the Java tag rather than Javascript?

Comment: I have updated it, does it work now?

Comment: Also I initially wrote it in java but will need to run it as javascript eventually, but has the java version works as well even when I switch processing into javascript I thought it was fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're super close Lily, literally.

If you print the values of destination and location you'll notice they're getting **super** close, however, due to the increments they never "meet". The values never match (aren't equal).

You could easily swap your equals conditions for a more practical threshold distance condition (e.g. if the distance between the destination and location are smaller than 1px):

```
void reachDestination()
  {
    println(destination,location);
      //if ((destination.x == location.x) && (destination.y == location.y)) {
      if(dist(destination.x,destination.y,location.x,location.y) < 1){

        if(siteNumber < sites.size() -1){

          siteNumber++; // siteNumber = siteNumber + 1;
          destination = sites.get(siteNumber);
          changeDirection = true;

        }else{

          println("reached final site");

        }
        println("reachDestination");
    }
  }
```

Bare in mind that [dist()](https://processing.org/reference/dist_.html) uses the square root which could become a slow calculation for a large number of sites (due to sqrt), however you could use the squared distance instead.

Additionally, PVector has a [lerp()](https://processing.org/reference/PVector_lerp_.html) function that returns the interpolated position between two given positions (e.g. destination and site) and an interpolation amount (a value between 0.0 (start position) and 1.0 (end position)).

Here's a proof of concept sketch:

```
PVector[] destinations = {
  new PVector(10,10),
  new PVector(90,10),
  new PVector(90,90),
  new PVector(10,90)
};

float traversal = 0.0;

void setup(){

}
void draw(){
  background(255);

  //draw destinations
  for(PVector d : destinations){
    ellipse(d.x,d.y,9,9);
  }

  //calculate traversal
  PVector traversed = traversePoints(destinations,0.01);
  //draw traversal
  ellipse(traversed.x,traversed.y,3,3);
}

PVector traversePoints(PVector[] destinations,float speed){
  if(speed < 0){
    speed = 0.05;
  }
  //increment full path traversal  (the higher the increment, the faster the move)
  traversal += speed;
  //loop back to 0 when fully traversed 
  if(traversal > destinations.length) traversal = 0.0;
  //compute the current point index
  int pointIndex = (int)traversal;
  //compute the local traversal (0.0 -> 1.0 = 0% to 100% in between two points: current and next)
  float pointT = traversal - pointIndex;
  //compute the next current point index
  int pointIndexNext = (pointIndex + 1) % destinations.length; 

  //interpolate between current and next points using above local traversal, offsetting by the last mainHingeition)
  return PVector.lerp(destinations[pointIndex],
                            destinations[pointIndexNext],
                            pointT);
}
```

You can actually run this as demo bellow:

```js
var destinations;

var traversal = 0.0;

function setup(){
  createCanvas(100,100);
  destinations = [
    createVector(10,10),
    createVector(90,10),
    createVector(90,90),
    createVector(10,90)
  ];
}
function draw(){
  background(255);
  
  //draw destinations
  for(var i = 0 ; i < destinations.length; i++){
    var d = destinations[i];
    ellipse(d.x,d.y,9,9);
  }
  
  //calculate traversal
  var traversed = traversePoints(destinations,0.01);
  //draw traversal
  ellipse(traversed.x,traversed.y,3,3);
}

function traversePoints(destinations,speed){
  if(speed < 0){
    speed = 0.05;
  }
  //increment full path traversal  (the higher the increment, the faster the move)
  traversal += speed;
  //loop back to 0 when fully traversed 
  if(traversal > destinations.length) traversal = 0.0;
  //compute the current point index
  var pointIndex = Math.floor(traversal);
  //compute the local traversal (0.0 -> 1.0 = 0% to 100% in between two points: current and next)
  var pointT = traversal - pointIndex;
  //compute the next current point index
  var pointIndexNext = (pointIndex + 1) % destinations.length; 
  
  //interpolate between current and next points using above local traversal, offsetting by the last mainHingeition)
  return p5.Vector.lerp(destinations[pointIndex],
                            destinations[pointIndexNext],
                            pointT);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh this is great, it works!! Thank you so much. Is there a way to make it go back to the plant everytime it reaches 2 sites and then go back out? It seems like I need to add another if function but I don't want to overwrite what it is already doing (going from site to site).

Comment: With your current implementation notice how there's an if condition checking `siteNumber` ? Use that to check it gets to 2 and if so: 1. get it to go back to the start point. 2. reset `siteNumber` to 0 when it reaches that. Bare in mind all you're Site instances are the same: you might want to have a separate Site which which is the head quarters. If the answer was helpful feel free to vote up and / or accept if it was the solution to your questions ;)

Comment: Can we add "if's" under the "else"? For example I will have my main if that will tell the site to go to the next one and then the else I will put under it another "if reached 2 site then go home". But then I don't know where to do that second step to tell it to go to the third. Would that still be unde the "else" or so I need to create a new if after it all? Hope that makes sense

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand.

The first thing I'd do is create a separate Site instance to know which one's home and which ones are the other sites. Second is to keep track of what's the lorry state once it reaches a destination (home or other site) (how many sites has it visited currently, what site is it at, etc.) to then decide (if condition) what it should do next.

Comment: Do you mean that I need to create maybe a new site Array that will store the site that the lorry has reached as a new "start point"?  Do you have an example on how that could be done?

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately I can't provide a full working code example, however, what I mean is creating something like `Site home;` at the top(initialized with the home coordinates). This way you can check if `destination == home` and figure out where to go next (also based on `siteNumber` or any other rule that fits the logic you need)